How to fix MUI The `anchorEl` prop provided to the component is invalid
I am trying to open the filter action menu nearby the Filters text where I clicked, but it is opening at the top corner of left side.
When I click on it, then in console I can see following issue:

MUI: The anchorEl prop provided to the component is invalid

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { TextField, IconButton, Menu, MenuItem, Grid, Button, Box, FormControl, Tooltip, Typography, InputAdornment, ThemeProvider, createTheme, Toolbar } from '@mui/material';
import { MoreVert as MoreVertIcon, Add as AddIcon } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { DataGridPro } from '@mui/x-data-grid-pro';
import densityIcon from '../../assets/icons/density-icon.svg';
import filterIcon from '../../assets/icons/filter-icon.svg';
import { GridSearchIcon } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

const Forms = () => {
  // Sample data for the table
  const data = [
    { id: 1, formName: 'Form 1', associateAPIName: 'API 1', status: 'Active' },
    { id: 2, formName: 'Form 2', associateAPIName: 'API 2', status: 'Inactive' },
    // Add more data as needed
  ];

  // State and handlers for Filters menu
  const [anchorElFilters, setAnchorElFilters] = React.useState(null);
  const handleMenuOpenFilters = (event) => {
    setAnchorElFilters(event.currentTarget);
    console.log(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleMenuCloseFilters = () => {
    setAnchorElFilters(null);
  };

  // State and handlers for Density menu
  const [anchorElDensity, setAnchorElDensity] = React.useState(null);
  const handleMenuOpenDensity = (event) => {
    setAnchorElDensity(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleMenuCloseDensity = () => {
    setAnchorElDensity(null);
  };

  const columns = [
    { field: 'formName', headerName: 'Form Name', flex: 0.5 },
    { field: 'associateAPIName', headerName: 'Associate API Name', flex: 0.5 },
    {
      field: 'status',
      headerName: 'Status',
      flex: 0.2,
      renderCell: (params) => (
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center', minWidth: '100%' }}>
          {params.value}
          <IconButton onClick={handleMenuOpenFilters}>
            <MoreVertIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Menu anchorEl={anchorElFilters} open={Boolean(anchorElFilters)} onClose={handleMenuCloseFilters}>
            <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuCloseFilters}>Action 1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuCloseFilters}>Action 2</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuCloseFilters}>Action 3</MenuItem>
          </Menu>
        </div>
      ),
    },
  ];

  const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
      MuiOutlinedInput: {
        styleOverrides: {
          notchedOutline: {
            borderWidth: '0px',
            borderColor: 'transparent',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });
  

  return (
    <Grid container overflow="scroll" height="100vh" pb={8}>
      <Grid item md={1}></Grid>
      <Grid item md={10}>
        <Box display="flex" justifyContent="flex-end" py={3}>
          <Button variant="contained">
            <AddIcon /> Add New Form 
          </Button>
        </Box>
        {/* DataGridPro */}
        <DataGridPro
          rows={data}
          columns={columns}
          autoHeight
          disableColumnFilter
          disableColumnSelector
          getRowId={(row) => row.id}
          components={{
            Toolbar: () => (
              <>
                <Box borderBottom={1} borderColor="rgba(224, 224, 224, 1)" pb={0}>
                  <Toolbar>
                    {/* Filters and Density side by side */}
                    <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Tooltip title="Filters">
                        <IconButton onClick={handleMenuOpenFilters}>
                            <img src={filterIcon} alt="filter-icon"/>
                          </IconButton>
                        </Tooltip>
                      </FormControl>
                      <Typography sx={{cursor: 'pointer'}} color={'#2196F3'} onClick={handleMenuOpenFilters}>FILTERS</Typography>
                
                      <FormControl sx={{ ml: 2 }}>
                        <Tooltip title="Density">
                        <IconButton onClick={handleMenuOpenDensity}>
                            <img src={densityIcon} alt="density-icon"/>
                          </IconButton>
                        </Tooltip>
                      </FormControl>
                      <Typography sx={{cursor: 'pointer'}} color={'#2196F3'} onClick={handleMenuOpenDensity}>DENSITY</Typography>
                    </div>
                    {/* Search field on the right */}
                    <div style={{ marginLeft: 'auto', height: 30 }}>
                      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                        <TextField
                          placeholder='Search'
                          sx={{
                            height: 30,
                            '& .MuiOutlinedInput-input': {
                              padding: '0px',
                            },
                          }}
                          InputProps={{
                            startAdornment: (
                              <InputAdornment position="start">
                                <GridSearchIcon />
                              </InputAdornment>
                            ),
                            sx: { pr: '30px' },
                          }}
                          InputLabelProps={{
                            shrink: true,
                            sx: { mt: '-7px' },
                          }}
                        />
                      </ThemeProvider>
                    </div>
                  </Toolbar>
                </Box>
              </>
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item md={1}></Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default Forms;

What changes should I do to fix issue? Any help appreciated.

According to the documentation ... "An HTML element, or a function that returns one. It's used to set the position of the menu." --   Are you sure you are passing an HTML element?  I would print it out to the console and see exactly what you are trying to pass .. My guess by the looks of your code is you're trying to pass an object.

@Zak I've consoled it and this is what I am passing: <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body1 css-1gh4zsj-MuiTypography-root">FILTERS</p>
